# Retrieve Message Consuming Time in Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka

Suppose I have a topic called `topic1` in Kafka. And I have a consumer group called `group1` which has 8 consumers consuming messages from `topic1`.

If I searched for a message in the past from Kafka, how can I get which consumer did cosume this message and when?

Comment: if you kept logger for each message consuming you can find with that. Kafka only store the offset offset of for each consumer group partition wise [and only the latest offset]

Comment: That's what I already know. I'm asking to see if there is another way without the need to add a logger at the consumer side.

Answer (score 1):

Kafka doesn't store any information about what actions consumers take ; it only cares about the offsets they commit back (if they do at all)

As commented, you're better off using log collection frameworks along with systems like Elasticsearch or Splunk for searching for such historical information